# trying to get random line from text document (python)

Tags: python, for-loop, discord, discord.py

I'm new to python and was working on a discord bot with Discord.py. I was trying to make it so when you type %quote it would get a random line from a text file. but for some reason it skips the first line or two. maybe I'm getting the logic wrong? here's my code.

```
@commands.command()
    async def quote(self, ctx, Qnum='janfol91213ｓｄｆ2uieh１あ2Ⅳ3ｓんｋｓｎaaksd'):
            i = 0
            if Qnum == 'janfol91213ｓｄｆ2uieh１あ2Ⅳ3ｓんｋｓｎaaksd':
                f = open("cogs\Base\data\Quotes.txt")
                random_lines = random.choice(f.readlines())
                await ctx.send(random_lines)
            else:
                f = open("cogs\Base\data\Quotes.txt")
                for line in f:
                    if i == int(Qnum):
                        quote = f.readline()
                        f.close()
                        break
                    else:
                        i = i+1
                await ctx.channel.send(quote)
                f.close()
```

the random Qnum thing is for optional parameter or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your txt file looks something like this:

```
quote1
quote2
```

you could read the txt file and split it with \n, like this:

```py
import random
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    read = f.read()
    array = read.split('\n')
    quote = random.choice(array)
await ctx.channel.send(quote)
```

to make sure it doesnt skip any lines, you can print the array with the quotes to the console, with print(array)

Comment: I wasn't referring to the random one but that array thing helped me out. it works now thanks!